# Firefox disable cycle between start-end of tabs with Ctrl+Tab?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I disable the cyclic nature of <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> in Firefox?

Currently if I press <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> again and again, repeatedly, when I hit the last tab, and press again, Firefox goes to the first tab. How can I disable this? (And also disable vice-versa.) I would like Firefox to stop on the last tab, like a tab-stop.

Note: I would like to *keep* the <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> shortcut for in-between tabs. Only the start/end should behave differently (by not cycling).

Comment: Note that if you overshoot, Ctrl+Shift+Tab will go backwards.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar yes I know, thanks! :) Just trying to customize it to work more how I would like it.